# Using already existing container python interpreter as PyCharm interpreter

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I have latest PyCharm installed.
I have a docker container and I want to use its python interpreter as my project interpreter. Note that I don't want PyCharm to create new container from image every time I run my script. What are the steps to do so?
If I use container interpreter will PyCharm support code completion for the packages installed in containers interpreter?

Comment: Why not just use your host's Python, maybe with a virtual environment for package isolation?  What's wrong with creating a new container every time you run the script?

Comment: @DavidMaze The container is bundled with ready to use packages. In addition, my host is Windows and the software does not support Windows.

Comment: I'd advise to just bind-mount your app directory into your container, and launch the app from there. It doesn't seem that Pycharm allows you not to rebuild the container every time.

Comment: @Faeeria Indeed, PyCharm builds a new container every time I run a script. Is not there anyway to run a container once instead of creating and removing it every time?!

Comment: Not with Pycharm. But you can run the container yourself with the Docker daemon, and bind-mount your app directory in your container.

Comment: @Faeeria Yeah. But my whole point was to integrate the scripting process INSIDE PyCharm

Comment: I understand. But that is not possible inside Pycharm. Unless you use Docker compose in Pycharm. Docker compose will stop and restart the containers, not delete and rebuild them.

Comment: @Faeeria How can I use docker compose to do that?

Comment: Well, first of all : do you really want docker as an interpreter, or would it be okay to use it as an execution environment ? (that seems closer to your use case)

Comment: @Faeeria I have got python installed inside docker container which contains specific packages. My goal is to be able to use container interpreter and have code completion in PyCharm and be able to run the code inside container and see the result.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#example

Comment: I personnally would use it as an execution environment and consult the logs, but that also works.

Answer (score 4):

I've submitted a feature request on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-53854 because this is simply not a feature in PyCharm.

One temporary solution I considered was to ask PyCharm to use the python from the Dockerfile: `docker exec -it container-name python`, but PyCharm unfortunately doesn't let me set a "command" as a python interpreter for the IDE. It does allow you to set the command for specific run/debug configurations though - so you could use the python interpreter in a running container if you don't want integration with the editor (e.g. import suggestions).

---

> **User:** Is there a technical reason as to why PyCharm cannot use an interpreter inside an already running container? Or could I expect it to be part of a future release? It would be a very nice feature to have

> **Jetbrains team:** I am not aware of any technical reasons. I couldn't find any feature request for it.
>
> Please feel free to submit a feature request about it to our issue tracker using the link https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY and let us know if you need any help.